# Removing Linux from Dual Boot Machine

Tags: windows, boot, dualboot

I have a Dell Latitude 3560 laptop that was, of course, delivered with Windows 10. When it was received, I shrunk the Windows partition down to 60GB and installed Fedora 28. The machine boots into Fedora properly and can boot Windows by selecting it from the grub screen.

I don't get much use out of the machine (I have others) and want to remove all the Linux partitions and re-grow the Windows partition, so somebody else can use it.

I don't have Windows install media, since the system came pre-installed.

I'm afraid that if I delete the Linux partitions, I'll have no MBR and it won't boot at all.

How can I preserve a boot record so the machine will continue to boot Windows 10?

Thanks, Ed

Comment: You might wish to contact Dell, get or make the recovery USB, and simply recover the machine to factory specs. This might be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bcdboot` command on Windows to reinstall the bootloader.

```
bcdboot c:\windows
```

If you're on a BIOS-boot system, bcdboot should install the Windows standard MBR boot code, overwriting GRUB's MBR.

(It won't remove the remainder of GRUB from the post-MBR gap but there's nothing that'll look there, so it doesn't matter.)

If you're on an UEFI system, then the Windows bootloader never went anywhere – UEFI doesn't use the MBR bootcode, it uses files in the EFI System Partition – but bcdboot will nevertheless ensure that Windows Boot Manager will be 1st in the UEFI boot order.

(The leftover GRUB boot entry can then be removed using `bcdedit /enum firmware` and `/delete {the_grub_guid}`, and the files can be manually removed from the EFI System Partition.)

Comment: I doubt that `bcdboot` will overwrite the MBR boot code. Better just use `bootsect` with `/mbr`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options

Comment: Hmm yes, that's probably true for BIOS systems.